# How to set background color of DataRow in DataTable c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, datarow

I am exporting my DataTable to Excel.
So before exporting, I added a new row, I want to set some background color to this row.
Here is my code...

```
                    DataRow newRow = datatable3.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < datatable3.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        newRow[i] = "Hello";
                    }

                //newRow.BackGroundColor = "Red" - Something like this.
```

Here I am exporting my DataTable to Excel.

```
                  using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                        {
                            //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, dt.TableName.ToString());
                        }
                        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                            return File(MyMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", ext);
                        }
                    }
```

It is showing like this .

[image]

How to change row background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are using ClosedXMS dll. [check their documentation on using colors](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Colors)

Answer (score 1):

@Gopal

Just being a little specific to @Conor's answer!. You can try this-

//For a specific Datatable in a list of multiple

```
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, dt.TableName.ToString());
for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[3].Columns.Count; j++) //This is for fourth datatable/sheet
{
ws.Cell(2, j).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(255, 255, 0); //All columns of second row
}
```

XlColor.FromArgb(//RGB Color Code); This static method gives you the liberty of specifying the RGB color code which you can easily get through the excel template you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Interior property found on an Excel.Range.

```
// The following just shows how the variables are created (based on creating a new Excel Spreadsheet)
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
var xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
// Now the actual code needed
var xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
// This select the entire top row, but you can select your own range based on your data
var titleRange = xlRange.Range["A1", string.Concat(((char)(xlRange.Columns.Count + 64)), 1)];
// The following line sets the fill colour
titleRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
```